# CSS / JS make only one of the divs resize/scroll to fixed footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, fixed

SOLVED: Thanks for all your help everyone!

The snippet below shows what my issue looked like before it was solved. The div "words" wasn't able to be scrolled no matter what CSS edits I made. I wanted just the one div "words" from the body to scroll not the entire content between the header and footer.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the snippet feature and provide an working example of your issue. It will ease helpers work and it will raise the amount and quality of helper who is gonna help you out. :)

Comment: @JonathanGagne thanks for that recommendation. I don't know how to use the snippet feature. I will try looking for it now

Comment: Inside the edit box tool bar, there is a button named `Snippet`. Click on it and split your `html` code into the `html` code block, the `css` code into the `css` part and then you can take a look on the end result by clicking on `Run`. If the result satisfy you, click on `Save` and write down your question before and/or after the snippet code block.

Comment: @JonathanGagne I was able to add a Snippet! Thanks for recommending it - hopefully I can find a solution now

Comment: My pleasure!!! Thank you for making Stack Overflow a better place to live where people are nice and smart ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that "words" is extending off the bottom of the page.  For scrolling to work like that on div tag you need to give it a static height, otherwise, the div will automatically adjust to the height of it's content and behave just like a normal div tag.

To make it responsive, you will need to use `screen.height;` in javaScript to get your total screen height, then subtract heights of your header and footer areas, and then set the div tag's height using the result.  For best results, use something like `window.setInterval(setWordsHeight(), 100);` to recheck the height of the screen on an interval so that it does not get messed up if someone resizes their window.

```
var headerFooterHeight = 200; 
window.setInterval( function(){
    document.getElementById("words").style.height = (window.innerHeight - headerFooterHeight)+"px"; 
console.log(document.getElementById("words").style.height);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @Nosjimiki. I am not too well versed in java. Can you give me a working code I can paste into mine using your example so I can test it's responsiveness?

Comment: Try this.  You may need need to re-adjust your "headerFooterHeight" to whatever your exact margin is.  Also, just so you know, Java and JavaScript are two completely different programming languages.

Comment: Will this work in all browsers? Would it be better to just add a second header like I am working on in @MartinBA's answer? I wouldn't want users to experience any issues with javascript if it's not universal on the average browser. (Thanks for letting me know the two were different languages).

Comment: Everything in this example should be cross platform compatible. The second header idea will become in issue if you have  a really long list.  The header is not actually making the scroll bar shorter, it's just hiding the top part of it; so, if you had a long list, it would hide the scroll bar controller and render it undraggable; so, I would not personally recommend that.

Comment: I pasted `<script>
var headerFooterHeight = 200; // Or whatever the total height of the header+footer is.
function setWordsHeight(){
  document.getElementById("words").style.height = (screen.height - headerFooterHeight)+"px";
}
window.setInterval(setWordsHeight(), 100); // this makes it recheck the size of the window every 100ms.
</script>` in my html and it did nothing

Comment: I think I got it to work! I had to change `class` to `id` for `words` and it;'s working now! Is there a way I can change the correct answer to yours?

Comment: great, also you may need to swap out screen.height for window.innerHeight so that it works properly in windowed, mode.

Comment: Alright @Nosajimiki everything works perfectly except for resizing the browser window vertically. It doesn't refresh the scrollbar live and ends up showing the div cutoff. I have to manually refresh for the script to make a new size. Is there a way to have it automatically do this live as the user is resizing their browser?

Comment: the setInterval thing should cause it to refresh every 100ms. Try copying the current version.  For whatever reason, when I tested it, it did not like having the named function from my previous example.

Comment: I noticed when I zoom in on the text half of the contents disappear and the div scroll area becomes so small only a few lines are showing. Is there a way to modify the JS to not let it resize on zoom?

Comment: The easiest solution is to disable zooming with: <meta name='viewport'  content='initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />.  As long as your defaults fonts are (16px / 12pt / 1em) or larger, and not low contrast, you should be compliant WCAG2.0 recommendations, and disabling zooming should not a significant issue.  That said, using pt/em is recommended since mobile retina displays can sometimes force text to half size when measured in px.

Comment: I have a new question I posted a few days ago. Can you check it out and see if you’d be able to help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227911/ajax-live-search-won-t-echo-no-matches-found

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `position: fixed;` for `#content`

```
#content {
 padding: 60px 0;
}
```

and also the `overflow-y: hidden;` from `body`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And for the last delete `overflow-y: scroll;` from `.words`

```
.words {
 text-align: left;
 margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

That should solve your problem, let me know if that help!

**Edit 1**

So first of all we need to update the markup, let's create a new container div and give it the class `.new-header`, this needs to be outside the `#content` div

```
<div class="new-header">
   <a class="hoverontouch" href="https://www.dollarresources.com">
      <div class="worldwide grow WorldWide">
      </div>
       </a>

        <div class="search-bar">
         <div class="search-button">
         <form action="search_keyword.php">
              <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search Dollar Resources..." required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a search word or phrase')"
     oninput="setCustomValidity('')" autocomplete="off"  onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
    onblur="this.placeholder = 'Search Dollar Resources...'">
              <button type="submit" value="Submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
    <?php

    // include "search_keyword.php";

    $mysqli->close();

    ?>
       </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, inside the `.new-header` div you have all the information needed for the second header, and then you need to add this css

```
.new-header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Now we need to give to the `#content` div more padding-top

```
#content {
 padding: 170px 0 60px 0;
}
```

Let me know if you have any problems applying this.

Comment: Good answer, but also remove overflow-y: scroll; from words so that you don't get the second unusable scrollbar.

Comment: @MartinBA, first of all thank you for your suggestions. This makes the entire content area scroll in between the header and footer. That's not what I want. I only want the div class: words to scroll. Can you make that possible?

Comment: In that case, you need my answer.  You need to give your div a set height.

Comment: If you want that, yes you need @Nosajimiki 's answer

Comment: @Nosajimiki, thank you for your suggestion as well. I tried commenting on your response but couldn't get it to work. How can I set it to a height and have it responsive with the browser resized vertically? I need it to be responsive

Comment: @MartinBA do you think I can add the three div classes "worldwide", "search-bar", and "search-button, as a second header fixed right under the first header? Then I can use your method to make words scroll by itself?

Comment: @SCodeSK71 Yes, I would totally do that, you will need to add more padding top to #content, but I think is the best choice.

Comment: @MartinBA thanks for the quick response. Can you show me a example with my code of doing that? I’ve never made two headers. I would like the current header and then another header fixed right under that including the three divs “worldwide, search-bar, and search-button” and then the div “words” under that above the footer using your original suggestion

Comment: @SCodeSK71 Yes I can, slow day at work, give me couple of minutes and I will edit the answer.

Comment: @MartinBA I think this is definitely the solution. But before I confirm that it is I tested it in Microsoft's Edge browser, and because I removed the overflow-y: hidden code you recommended from the page, the entire webpage now bounces when you scroll all the way to the top or bottom of the page. But only in the Edge browser. You can test it at this link if you can in Edge. I updated the code to website with everything you recommended at https://www.dollarresources.com/test.php without messing up the original code on the original error page I posted

Comment: Ok, I can't test it now, later I will do it

Comment: @MartinBA no need to, I just realized that bounce in Edge is a default of the browser and does it to every site from google to microsoft and more. No worries. Thanks again for all your help! I'll be using the two fixed headers for now and will mark this answer the best/correct

Comment: @SCodeSK71 Great! I’m glad to help!

Comment: Because @Nosajimiki made a good point that we are hiding the scrollbar with the second header and that could make issues with large content I decided to use java script instead and it's working perfectly for now. I appreciate both your help

Comment: Ok, I respect the decision, but it's not true, if a second fixed header is a problem, the first header is a problem too, just imagine the two header as a one large header, the header will never interfeer with the scroll, it has a fixed position, that means it's not in the flow of the page, just try it, add a looong list of lorem ipsum, you will see that is working perfectly