# Display “No matches found” or hide DIV results (AJAX & MySQL)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a search bar that works for displaying AJAX live search results with MySQL, PHP, and JS.

The problem is I can’t figure out how to get the search results to display “No matches found” or hide the results `div` completely when a query doesn’t match any “Name” in the MySQL database.

Currently, when a user types something into the search bar that doesn’t match any “Name” in the database, a blank result pops up under the AJAX live search result. I would instead like for the message “No matches found” to take over that blank result.

I have tried a number of else / if / echo codes and combinations in different orders and nothing has worked so far. I am also trying a different method of showing / hiding a div that displays “No matches found” based on the results.

How can I fix this code once and for all so that when the user searches any name that doesn’t match any name in the MySQL database, it will display "No matches found"?

Below are the files and codes I am currently using:

**index.php**

```
<form>  
 <input type="text" id="search" class="search" data-js="form-text" 
  placeholder="Search Over 100+ Resources..." autocomplete="off">
 <button type="submit" class="Button" value="Submit"><i class="fa fa- 
  search"></i></button>
 <div id="display"></div>
<div id="no-results" style="display:none"><ul><li id='hover'>No matches 
 found</li></ul></div>
</form>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
//Including Database configuration file.
include "db.php";
//Getting value of "search" variable from "script.js".
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
//Search box value assigning to $Name variable.
$Name = $_GET['search'];
//Search query.
$Query = "SELECT Name FROM search WHERE Name LIKE '$Name%' LIMIT 5";
//Query execution
$ExecQuery = MySQLi_query($con, $Query);
//Creating unordered list to display result.
 echo '<ul>';
 //Fetching result from database.
 while ($Result = MySQLi_fetch_array($ExecQuery)) {
   ?>
 <!-- Creating unordered list items.
    Calling javascript function named as "fill" found in "script.js" file.
    By passing fetched result as parameter. -->
 <li onclick='fill("<?php echo $Result['Name']; ?>")'>
 <a>
 <!-- Assigning searched result in "Search box" in "index.php" file. -->
   <?php 
 if ($ExecQuery > "0") {
 echo $Result['Name'];
 }
 else {
  echo "<li id='hover'>No matches found</li>";
 }
?>
</li></a>
<!-- Below php code is just for closing parenthesis. Don't be confused. -->
<?php
}}

?>
</ul>
```

**script.js**

```
//Getting value from "ajax.php".
function fill(Value) {
//Assigning value to "search" div in "index.php" file.
$('#search').val(Value);
//Hiding "display" div in "index.php" file.
$('#display').hide();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
//On pressing a key on "Search box" in "index.php" file. This function will 
be called.
$('#no-results').hide();
$("#search").keyup(function() {
   //Assigning search box value to javascript variable named as "name".
   $('#display').hide();
   $('#no-results').css("display", "none");
   var name = $('#search').val();
   //Validating, if "name" is empty.
   if (name == "") {
       //Assigning empty value to "display" div in "index.php" file.
       $('#no-results').css("display", "none");
   }
   //If name is not empty.
   else {
       //AJAX is called.
       $.ajax({
           //AJAX type is "Post".
           type: "GET",
           //Data will be sent to "ajax.php".
           url: "ajax.php",
           //Data, that will be sent to "ajax.php".
           data: {
               //Assigning value of "name" into "search" variable.
               search: name
           },
           //If result found, this funtion will be called.
           success: function(html) {
               //Assigning result to "display" div in "index.php" file.
               $("#display").html(html).show();
           }
       });
   }
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

you should check your data that is valid and you have any result from your database query or not, if there is no record then you can print not found data message.
you should check the output of `$ExecQuery` and set `if` condition according to that.
let me now your output and result I hope this helps you.

**Update ajax.php**
Last updated section

```
echo "<li onclick='fill(`".$Result['Name']."`)'>".$Result['Name']."</li>";
```

**Complete ajax.php**

```
  <?php
    //Including Database configuration file.
    include "db.php";
    //Getting value of "search" variable from "script.js".
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
//Search box value assigning to $Name variable.
$Name = $_GET['search'];
//Search query.
$Query = "SELECT Name FROM search WHERE Name LIKE '$Name%' LIMIT 5";
//Query execution
$ExecQuery = MySQLi_query($con, $Query);
//Creating unordered list to display result.
    if ($ExecQuery->num_rows > 0) {
         echo "<ul>";
         while ($Result = MySQLi_fetch_array($ExecQuery)) {
            // use the onclick function that defined in js file. you can use the `  sign in js instead of ' if you needed.
            echo "<li onclick='fill(`".$Result['Name']."`)'>".$Result['Name']."</li>";
         }
        echo "</ul>";
    }else{
        echo "<ul><li>No Result Found!</li></ul>";      
    }
}
die();
?>
```

**and your ajax code.**

```
function fill(value) {
  console.log(value);
  $('#search').val(value);
  $('#display').hide();
}
 $(document).ready(function() {
//On pressing a key on "Search box" in "index.php" file. This function will be called.
$("#search").keyup(function() {
   //Assigning search box value to javascript variable named as "name".
   $('#display').hide();
   $('#no-results').css("display", "none");
   var name = $('#search').val();
   //Validating, if "name" is empty.
   if (name == "") {
       //Assigning empty value to "display" div in "index.php" file.
       $('#no-results').css("display", "block");
   }
   //If name is not empty.
   else {
       //AJAX is called.
       $.ajax({
           //AJAX type is "Post".
           type: "GET",
           //Data will be sent to "ajax.php".
           url: "ajax.php",
           //Data, that will be sent to "ajax.php".
           data: {
               //Assigning value of "name" into "search" variable.
               search: name
           },
           //If result found, this funtion will be called.
           success: function(html) {

           if (html == '<ul><li>No Result Found!</li></ul>') {
              $('#no-results').css("display", "block");
            }else{
               //Assigning result to "display" div in "index.php" file.
                 $("#display").html(html).show();
             }

           }
       });
   }
 });
 });
```

change other parts as you need.

Comment: @SCodeSK71 do you have ajax code? please check your question and update it with all related parts (HTML,PHP, Ajax and any  related block of code that you have)

Comment: How about this to make things easier. Is there a way to just show nothing if there isn't a "Name" match in MySql? For example if the user types "dhjfahdjhsjk" no box will pop out under the search bar. I'm fine with the ajax live search not triggered at all if there are no matching names in the database.

Comment: @SCodeSK71 I rewrite the answers according to your feedback, please check it again and let me know that it help you.

Comment: Why did you remove the code `//Getting value from "ajax.php". function fill(Value) { //Assigning value to "search" div in "index.php" file. $('#search').val(Value); //Hiding "display" div in "index.php" file. $('#display').hide(); }` from my original code? Now my fill function is not working. I tried to add it to your code but it doesn't work anymore. Can you make the fill function in my `JS` file work with your code?

Comment: I posted the new issue as a new question if you can help solve it here or there at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286480/echo-js-onclick-fill-function-ajax-not-working

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is Asynchronous Javascript and XML. Why send back HTML ?

Pointers

- If you're doing this via Ajax I would highly dis-advise sending pure HTML. You should send back some JSON data and handle it accordingly client side.
- Use PDO instead of MySQLi

Solution PHP

```
<?php
include "db.php";
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $Name = $_POST['search'];
  $Query = "SELECT Name FROM search WHERE Name LIKE '$Name%' LIMIT 5";
  $ExecQuery = MySQLi_query($con, $Query);

  $res = [];
  while ($Result = MySQLi_fetch_array($ExecQuery)) {
    $res[] = $Result['Name'];
  }

  echo json_encode($res);
}
```

Solution Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  //AJAX type is "Post".
  type: "POST",
  //Data will be sent to "ajax.php".
  url: "ajax.php",
  //Data, that will be sent to "ajax.php".
  data: {
    //Assigning value of "name" into "search" variable.
    search: name
  },
  //If result found, this funtion will be called.
  success: function(data) {
    //Assigning result to "display" div in "search.php" file.
    const list = JSON.parse(data);
    const html = list.length > 0 ? 
      list.map(name=>{
        `<li onclick="${name}">
           <a>${name}</a>
        </li>`
      }).join("") :
      `<li>No matches found</li>`

    $("#display").html(`<ul>${html}</ul>`).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: @SCodeSK71 hey, sorry I guess we live in different time zones..  I was waiting on your comment. I'll take a look after work.

Comment: Thanks for helping I will read up on JSON and PDO. I have it working for now but a new issue popped up where the onclick fill function isn't working. I've posted it as a new question here if you could possibly help answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286480/echo-js-onclick-fill-function-ajax-not-working