# how to create a dependent drop-down for classes based on the selected college

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to create a dependent drop down list on the other dropdown, when the user click the college of students the class belong to that college only display in the dropdown

```
<!-- class list --> 
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Class</label>
                        <select required name="class_id" id="class-dropdown" class="form-select form-select-sm lg">
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <?php 
                            $classes = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT id, concat(course, ' ', year_level, ' - ', section) as class FROM class_list GROUP BY course, year_level, section ORDER BY year_level ASC");
                            $c_arr = array();
                            while($row = $classes->fetch_assoc()):
                              $c_arr[$row['id']] = $row;
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
                            <?php echo isset($class_id) && $class_id == $row['id'] ? "selected" : "" ?>>
                            <?php echo $row['class'] ?></option>
                          <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>

                      <!-- college list -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">College</label>
                        <select required name="college_id" id="college-dropdown" class="form-select form-select-sm lg">
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <?php 
                              $colleges = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT id, code FROM college_list GROUP BY id");
                              $cl_arr = array();
                              while($row = $colleges->fetch_assoc()):
                                $cl_arr[$row['id']] = $row;
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
                            <?php echo isset($college_id) && $college_id == $row['id'] ? "selected" : "" ?>>
                            <?php echo $row['code'] ?></option>
                          <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select>
                      </div>
```

the ajax iadded in my code, but after clicking the college and click the class dropdown menu it says no result found

```
  <script>
    document.getElementById('college-dropdown').addEventListener('change', function() {
      var collegeId = this.value;
      var classDropdown = document.getElementById('class-dropdown');

      // Clear the class dropdown
      classDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value=""></option>';

      if (collegeId) {
        // Fetch classes using AJAX
        fetch('fetch_classes.php?college_id=' + collegeId)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            // Populate the class dropdown with the fetched classes
            data.forEach(function(row) {
              var option = document.createElement('option');
              option.value = row.id;
              option.text = row.class;
              classDropdown.add(option);
            });
          });
      }
    });
  </script>
```

```html
this is my fetch_classes.php file to fetch the class in my database

<?php
  require_once './config.php'; // Include your database connection file

  $college_id = $_GET['college_id'];

  $classes = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT id, concat(course, ' ', year_level, ' - ', section) as class FROM class_list WHERE college_id = $college_id GROUP BY course, year_level, section ORDER BY year_level ASC");

  $data = array();
  while($row = $classes->fetch_assoc()):
    $data[] = $row;
  endwhile;

  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: For that you would need Ajax JavaScript to. Get the data an display then

Comment: i try to add a Ajax JavaScript but it says no result found

Comment: No te ajax will call a PHP script that fetches the data and send it back to the JavaScript and then you process it see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227911/display-no-matches-found-or-hide-div-results-ajax-mysql. And there are plenty of tutorials how to do them and how to debug the code it is a good reac